# serving images using Webrick

Tags: ruby, webrick

I need to grab a some images from a folder on a users computer and display them on a webpage using a webrick server. I am using the following code to scan the directory and then include the path to the webserver. I am getting correct paths to the images but I am getting an error 404 from Webrick when I try to access the page. I have been moving files around and changing permissions without any success. I have a feeling webrick is running from a location buried inside the usr folder but I'm not sure how to check this and how to correctly create an image path for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'webrick' 
include WEBrick

s = HTTPServer.new(Port: 2000)

class HelloServlet < HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet 

def do_GET(req, res)

  search_dir = 'users/user/Dropbox/ads_dir'
  files = Dir[ search_dir + '/*.jpg']
  p @file0 = files[0].to_s    
  p @file1 = files[1].to_s    
  p @file2 = files[2].to_s    
  p @file3 = files[3].to_s 

res['Content-Type'] = "text/html"
res.body = %{
        <img class="img1" src="#{@file0}"/>
        <img class="img2" src="#{@file1}"/>
        <img class="img3" src="#{@file2}"/>     
        <img class="img4" src="#{@file3}"/>
  </body> 
  </html>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images path is like `/home/users/images` you should declare the `DocumentRoot`:

```
s = HTTPServer.new(Port: 2000, DocumentRoot: "/home/users")
```

And then you can get access to the image:

```
http://localhost/images/image1.jpg
```